# blocks and variable scope in Ruby

Tags: ruby

From p.226 of Russ Olsen's *Eloquent Ruby*:

> All of the variables that are visible just before the opening **do** or **{**
>   are still visible inside a code block. Code blocks drag along the scope in which they were created wherever they go.

To see this for myself, I ran the following code

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @a = 1
  end

  def show_a
    puts "from method: value of a is #{@a}"
    yield
  end
end

bar = Foo.new

bar.show_a {puts "from block: value of a is #{@a}"}
```

The output, to my surprise, is

> from method: value of a is 1
>
> from block: value of a is

Why is the value of @a not making it into the block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right before `bar.show_a {puts "from block: value of a is #{@a}"}`, stick in a `puts @a`. That will be nil as well. You will find that there is no `@a` instance variable visible in that scope, because `@a` is an instance variable of the Foo class. So the block is faithfully reflecting the lack of an `@a` in the surrounding scope.

To put it another way: A block closes over the scope where it's *created*, not where it's *called*.